# How to add static libraries inside a C++ project with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm developing a **C++** project by using **Xcode** `4.6.1` as IDE.
Now, I'd like to add a static library `mylib.a` and the related header `mylib.h`.

I read about **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124523/linking-a-static-library-to-an-ios-project-in-xcode-4)**, but it doesn't work (while clicking on *Target Dependencies*, the box is still remaining empty).

Is there a way to achieve this task?

---

### UPDATE:

I created a *group*, then I added the file `mylib.a` on it. It seems to work fine, but at compile-time a warning as follows appears:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/vdenotaris/Desktop/Code/MyStaticLib/mylib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
(i386):/Users/vdenotaris/Desktop/Code/MyStaticLib/mylib.a
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add .a C static library to Xcode and use it there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830434/how-to-add-a-c-static-library-to-xcode-and-use-it-there)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Target dependencies is used if your static library is created by another *XCode* project and you want to include this project, so that you can easily develop on both you library and the corresponding application.

If you want to include a foreign library you would select your target under **TARGETS** there you select the section **Build Phases** there you have the area **Link Binary With Libraries** into this area you would add your library either with *drag & drop* or with the <kbd>+</kbd> sign.

To add the include path you select your project under **PROJECT** there you select the area **Build Settings** there you have under *Search Path* the Points **Header Search Paths** this should include the path to the directory where the header is.

The difference between the settings in *Project* or *Targets* is that in *Project* it sets the default settings for all targets. In *Targets* you can change the settings per *Target*.

**EDIT**
For the linking errors this two answers could be helpful:

- [static Library in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458390/static-library-in-xcode-4)
- [file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803211/file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-i386)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I linked inside my project `mylib.a`and `my lib.h`; now, when I build, appears the following warning: `ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/vdenotaris/Desktop/Code/MyStaticLib/mylib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/vdenotaris/Desktop/Code/MyStaticLib/mylib.a`. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: @vdenotaris are you developing an iOS app ?

Comment: No, I'm developing a C++ app for my Master's Thesis.

Comment: please show the _Architectures_, _Valid Architectures_ and _Supported Platforms_ for both you static library and application.

Comment: I suppose that the considered static library was built for x64,  whereas my project is based on i386 arch.

Comment: i thought it is your own library, cause of the path, if it is not your own you can check it in command line  with `lipo -info /Users/vdenotaris/Desktop/Code/MyStaticLib/mylib.a`

Comment: `input file mylib.a is not a fat file`
`Non-fat file: mylib.a is architecture: x86_64`

Comment: so your guess was right, the linking error is because your project is `i386` and the library is `x86_64`

Comment: Yes, I just now rebuild OpenCV (used inside my project) to support x86_64 arch and all works fine. Thank you so much.