# How to work with C shared header files on a Mac?

Tags: c, xcode

I'm experimenting with linking and sharing header files in C; I would like to share this function, `tool.c`, between many programs:

```
void sayHello() {
    printf("Hello!");
}
```

...I define the function in `tool.h`:

```
void sayHello();
```

It makes a lot of sense if other programs `#include tool.h` so that they can all call the `sayHello` function. I need to create a single program from multiple files. Here I can create an entirely different program (target) that calls the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/usr/someone/somewhere/tool.h"

int main() {
    sayHello();
}
```

Though, the linker process fails: `linker command failed with exit code 1`. If you wish, download the Xcode project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/caehipcbxw8b8x2/tool.zip?dl=0).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you linking with `tool.c`? Also it would be useful to post the error message rather than an image.

Comment: Thanks @FilipeGonçalves! What do you mean by "are you linking with"? I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not enough to include a header file with the function declaration - you need to tell the linker where to find the code for `sayHello()`. In the command line, you typically do this by indicating the additional files when invoking gcc, e.g. `gcc myprog.c tool.c` (or if `tool.c` is already compiled as a library, you indicate the corresponding library file). I don't know how to do it in XCode, but you can compile `tool.c` into a static library and then add it to the project dependencies - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973472/adding-static-libraries-to-a-c-based-project-with-xcode

Comment: So, first you create a static library (the way you do this is by creating an object file for `tool.o` with gcc and then use `ar(1)` to create the `.a` library - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734719/how-to-compile-a-static-library-in-linux). Then you include `tool.h` when you need to use it. Then you add the `.a` library file to the project dependencies list in XCode as shown in that question I mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. It is really helpful. The problem is that Xcode won't give the executable file until the program compiles. Since I have some errors, Xcode doesn't compile my C files. The error is `linker command failed with exit code 1` so there seems to be an issue with the linker process - just as you suggested. Have you got any tips Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should compile the library first, I'd say outside of XCode, so that you can get a standalone `.a` library file to add to the project dependencies (then you should be able to build the project). Use command-line tools, namely `gcc` and `ar`.

Comment: Do not post pictures if not really justified!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the header file in itself; while you included the header, you did not tell the linker where to find the actual definitions of your code. So you need to compile the .c file e.g. into a static library and add that to the linker options of your `other_tool`.

Comment: This is correct. In Xcode add a new C library and add compile and header files to it.